# Draft or backup versions

Tags: android

Is there a way to automatically control developing process, perhaps using versionCode + some draft attribute?

Since I am a newbie, I keep experimenting a lot, and encounter an errors which sometimes I don't understand. And then again, I would preferably retrieve previous draft version rather then resolving an error.

The best thing I came up with, is making another project with versionCode +1 and versionName "0.xx", where 0 stands for draft. Maybe after gaining some experience I wouldn't need anything better?

Comment: You don't have to create new projects with incremented version codes. There are a lot of version control tools. Just make a google search with the keyword **svn** or **git**. They will handle the version control for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so that's it. I get into git, made even account on bitbucket. Everyone was a newbie once.
Commit.